# Unexpected error message, reproduction apparently very fragile - bug?

Tags: z3

Running Windows x64 builds of Z3 4.3.2 (official download) and Z3 4.4 0ab54b9e0c33 on [this program](http://people.inf.ethz.ch/scmalte/tmp/logfile.zip) (which is unfortunately quite long) yields an `invalid rational value passed as an integer`.

The problem does not appear to be a type checker problem, because the apparently offending formula (the last `check-sat` in the program) looks fine type-wise:

```
(declare-const i@99 Int)
(declare-const k@38 Int)
...
(assert (not (and (<= 0 i@99) (< i@99 (+ k@38 1)))))
(check-sat) ; ERROR
```

My guess is that the problem occurs during proof search because marginally changing the program makes the error disappear. I experimented with changing Z3's configuration options and observed that the error disappears if `smt.arith.nl` is set to `false`, respectively, if `smt.qi.eager_threshold` is set to a value lower than `10`. Moreover, removing essentially any `push-pop` scope preceding the last `check-sat` also makes the error disappear (I didn't actually try to remove every single scope, though). Both observations make me believe that the error is raised during proof search and in an "area" of the search space that is only reached under specific circumstances.

The offending line as well as lines I experimented with are marked by `[XXX]`.

Is this a bug or is something else going on here?

Comment: This sounds like it erroneously generates a rational number where it expects an integer. I can reproduce the problem, but there's no fix yet. Adding to our bug tracker.

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger Which bug tracker id did it get?

Comment: We are moving to github, don't use the one on Codeplex anymore. This particular item is here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/32

Comment: See there; can't reproduce anymore, but may still not be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can be followed on Z3's GitHub page: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/32.